# Windows service started with domain admin account butwhen other domain account logon is shows that the service didn't start

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I've recently stumble across this problem but cannot fins a reason for this and a workaround.

I've logged on with my domain admin account on a server (Windows Server 2008 R2) and started a service that were set to start manually. After wards when another user with a domain account logged on and had a look at the service as were experiencing problems it showed that the service were in the stopped state although in my session which were still open it showed that it started.

He started the service and everything work after that.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? And on what to do rectify this or have a workaround for this?

Appreciate you comments and suggestions.

Comment: I'm guessing the service stopped for some reason between when you checked it and when the other user logged in.  The management console was just showing you out-of-date information, because you didn't press refresh.

Answer (score -1):

Your service does not to answer correctly to the SCM with SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE and it span another process with the StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(DispatchTable).

We **can't** do anything there unless you patch your application or contact your software vendor.

Comment: ah, sorry, newbie there

Comment: @yagmoth555 we all make mistakes! :) as long as you learn from it, it's fine

Comment: thx, editing my post, better now :)  but cant comment, it's bad to troubleshoot, how do you do guys to gain the first 50 points ? spot easy question ?